# Placing calls to super?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have asked this before, but the more I look at other code examples the more I see differences in layout. Usually I try and put the call to super at the start (if its a creation type method) or at the end (if its a destroy type method) (see below...)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   ...
   ...
}
```

.

```
-(void)viewDidUnload {
   ...
   ...
   [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

The other method I see always seems to place the call to super at the end of the method regardless. (see below...) my question is does it matter?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   ...
   ...
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

.

```
-(void)viewDidUnload {
   ...
   ...
   [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

cheers gary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that it doesn't usually matter, unless:

- The method is doing **initialisation** of instance variables (which `viewDidLoad` usually wouldn't be doing, as that's the `init` method's job), in which case the `super` call should be at the start.
- The method is doing **deallocation** of instance variables, in which case the `super` call should be at the end.
- The method is passing on some sort of event, e.g. through a responder chain, in which case you wouldn't actually be using a `super` call at all (but the pattern is similar), and you'd put the call at the end.

I may have missed some important cases, though.