# ViewDidLoad super

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In viewDidLoad do you put [super viewDidLoad] before or after your code? Is it the same for all other methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing calls to super?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466889/placing-calls-to-super)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before. You want the super initialization to happen before yours, so that your code could rely on the super state.

As for the other methods - it depends whether you want your code to touch the parameters before calling the super method or it needs to process the result of it.